# How to extract base 10 mantissa and exponent using gpmlib in C++

Tags: c++, gmp

I need to extract significand and exponent of a double in C++ using gpmlib.
Ex: double a =  1.234;
I would like to extract 1234 as significand and 3 as exponent so that a = 1234e-3. I heard that gpmlib supports this type functions. I am not sure how to this library.

Please share some sample code using this library.

Comment: I assume you mean gmp: The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're looking for [`mpf_class::get_str()`](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Floats.html#C_002b_002b-Interface-Floats), which will break up the floating-point value `1.234` into the string `"1234"` and the exponent `1`, because `1.234 == 0.1234 * 10^1`

You will need to subtract the size of the string from that exponent, to fit your requirements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <gmpxx.h>
int main()
{
    double a = 1.125; // 1.234 cannot be stored in a double exactly, try "1.234"
    mpf_class f(a);
    mp_exp_t exp;
    std::string significand = f.get_str(exp);
    std::cout << "significand = " << significand
              << " exponent = " << exp-(int)significand.size() << '\n';

}
```

This prints

```
~ $ ./test
significand = 1125 exponent = -3
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In my example I have double defined as 20.2345. The call to f.get_str(exp) returns 202345000000000005969 with exponent -19. But my expected value is 202345e-4 instead of 202345000000000005969e-19. How can I control the precesion?

Comment: @user715841 `ostringstream os; os << a; mpf_class f(os.str());` or just don't store it in a double to start with.

Comment: for others who attempt to use this code, it appears you must also allow for the sign if the number is negative `exp-(int)significand.size()` will return an incorrect value (off by one) if the number is negative.